What really is a function expression?
Can someone explain me please if a function expression involves the function value along the variable in where it's stored or is really only the function value?, so i always see that the "function expression" term points to this whole snippet:
const funcExp = function(){console.log("Hello World!")};

But i was wondering.. then what about this:
function(){console.log("Hello World!")}

if you ask me i would say that the function expression is only the function value itself, which basically would be a pure anonymous function, no? i could be wrong but.. do you really don’t think that would be strange to call this an anonymous function?:
const funcExp = function(){console.log("Hello World!")};

i mean in some way already has a name, not directly as part of the function value, but as part of the variable in where its stored, so i don't know i just want to know what really  is a function expression, the whole variable creation initialized with a function value or only that function value, if the first turns to be true then how do we call this type of function values function(){console.log("Hello World!")}? function expression also?; thanks.

There are function expressions, and there are function declaration statements.

The Wikipedia article on Immediately invoked function expression might clarify. They used to be very popular.

@ElliottFrisch I never stopped loving them

@Pointy (function(fn, msg) { fn(msg); })(console.log, 'I think we should keep things professional')


so i always see that the "function expression" term points to this whole snippet

Technically speaking, only the function(){console.log("Hello World!")} part of that line is a function expression. The left hand side is a variable declaration. But people will sometimes use the term "function expression" for this whole thing, to distinguish it from a "function declaration". Eg, the following as a standalone line is a function declaration:
function func() {console.log("Hello World!")};

Btw, if you're interested in the technical names of the various bits of syntax, i recommend playing around with https://astexplorer.net/ . You can paste in javascript and it will show a tree structure of what the various pieces of code are

i could be wrong but.. do you really don’t think that would be strange to call this an anonymous function?:

Because of the fact that you immediately assign it to a variable named funcExp, it actually does get a name. Eg, try the following:


const funcExp = function(){console.log("Hello World!")};
console.log(funcExp.name)



So i would personally not use the term "anonymous function", since it does end up with a name. If you don't assign it to a variable, then it won't have a name, and then i would call it anonymous:


function logName(fn) {
  console.log(fn.name);
}

logName(function(){console.log("Hello World!")})




"But people will sometimes use the term "function expression" for this whole thing" - then they're just wrong. And I think most people who show the whole statement don't actually mean it, they still refer to only the function part as the function expression; but of course one always needs to show what the function expression is a part of. Because if it wasn't part of something else, it wouldn't be a function expression :-)
